# Hive: How to find out a value base on previous row's value?

Tags: sql, hive

I have an IoT style data. I have to replace a "none" with the value that comes from the nearest time from that "none"(the value of that nearest time is not a "none").

Original data:

```
+---------------------+--------+
|     time            | value  |
|---------------------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 11:11:10 | "0.3"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:11 | "0.2"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:12 | "none" |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:13 | "none" |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:14 | "none" |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:15 | "0.1"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:16 | "none" |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:17 | "0.4"  |
+---------------------+--------+
```

Final data would be like this

```
+---------------------+--------+
|     time            | value  |
|---------------------+--------+
| 2020-01-01 11:11:10 | "0.3"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:11 | "0.2"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:12 | "0.2"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:13 | "0.2"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:14 | "0.2"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:15 | "0.1"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:16 | "0.1"  |
| 2020-01-01 11:11:17 | "0.4"  |
+---------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that "no value" is actually `NULL`.  Then you want `LAG(IGNORE NULLS)`, but Hive doesn't support that.  But you can do this with two steps.  Identify groups by counting the number of "real" values up to each row  Then use window functions to assign the value:

```
select t.*, max(value) over (partition by grp)
from (select t.*,
             count(value) over (order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

EDIT:

If you are actually storing the values as strings, and `'none'` is a real value, then just use a variant of the above:

```
select t.*,
       max(nullif(value, 'none')) over (partition by grp)
from (select t.*,
             count(nullif(value, 'none')) over (order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to [In HIVE replacing the Null value by the same column values using COALESCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820146/in-hive-replacing-the-null-value-by-the-same-column-values-using-coalesce/51820857)

With one minor difference:

```
with rank_table as ( 
select *, SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as rnk
  from your_table
)
select *, max(value) over (partition by rnk)
  from rank_table
```