# Repeat previous values by date in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have 2 tables - Dates and Data with data as follows:
Table: Dates

```
Date
1/02/2020
2/02/2020
3/02/2020
4/02/2020
5/02/2020
6/02/2020
7/02/2020
8/02/2020
9/02/2020
10/02/2020
```

Table: Data

```
Date    Id  Amount
1/02/2020   1   10
3/02/2020   1   30
10/02/2020  1   50
2/02/2020   2   5
6/02/2020   2   10
9/02/2020   2   20
```

Expected results:

```
Date    Id  Amount
1/02/2020   1   10
2/02/2020   1   10
3/02/2020   1   30
4/02/2020   1   30
5/02/2020   1   30
6/02/2020   1   30
7/02/2020   1   30
8/02/2020   1   30
9/02/2020   1   30
10/02/2020  1   50
2/02/2020   2   5
3/02/2020   2   5
4/02/2020   2   5
5/02/2020   2   5
6/02/2020   2   10
7/02/2020   2   10
8/02/2020   2   10
9/02/2020   2   20
```

I have tried using PARTITION OVER but getting duplicate vales and not all dates from Dates table, therefore not getting desired results. Really appreciate if you can help with the code in Hive SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows.  Then a `left join` combine the two tables.  And finally use `last_value()` to bring in missing values:

```
select d.date, i.id,
       last_value(amount, TRUE) over (partition by id order by d.date) as amount
from date d cross join
     (select distinct id from data) i left join
     data t
     on d.date = t.date and i.id = t.id;
```

The `last_value()` with the second argument ignores `NULL` values, so it will "go back" to get the most recent non-`NULL` value.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am getting "At least 1 group must only depend on inputs columns. Also check for circular dependencies" error. I have included amount in select statement, yet getting this error in my real data. Pls help.

Comment: It's working now. Instead of (amount, 1), I changed it to (amount, TRUE) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First outer join two tables, then following

```
with join_table as (
select coleasce(t1.date, t2.date) as date, t2.id, t2.amount
  from table1 as t1
  outer join table2 as t2
    on t1.date = t2.date
)
, rank_table as ( 
select *, SUM(id) OVER (ORDER BY d_day ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and CURRENT ROW) as id_rnk,
SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY d_day ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and CURRENT ROW) as amount_rnk
  from join_table
)
select *, max(id) over (partition by id_rnk), max(amount) over (partition by amount_rnk)
  from rank_table
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820146/in-hive-replacing-the-null-value-by-the-same-column-values-using-coalesce/51820857#51820857) for more details.